# How do I maintain a Set of event properites in a window?

Tags: esper, nesper

Is it possible to create a table with a primary key and a Set as a secondary column that would be like a list in a value of a hashtable?

something like this:

```
create table T (id int primary key, list HashSet )
```

where the list would hold all properties related to the primary key that happened over a window size.

EDIT:

This is the output I get. What I want is to keep count of unique Occurences arriving at id 1,2 and 3.
If Occurence 2 arrived 3 times at ID 1 I still only want 1 as unique, not 3

```
{unique=3, id=1}
{unique=3, id=2}
{unique=4, id=3}
****************
```

In java it is no problem, but I dont understand how to implement this in Esper. Im not even sure if using tables is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Tables can have aggregation-state-type columns. So the "window" aggregation is available. For example like this:

`create table MyTable (id int primary key, theWindow window(*) @type(MyEvent))`

```
into table MyTable select window(*) as theWindow from MyEvent group by id
```

Or the table could declare a list-type column "create table MyTable (id int primary key, somelist java.util.List)" and it is up to you to maintain the list via function calls in EPL.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I maintain the list? Where do I declare what type it should hold etc? in the create table statement or in the into statement? What I want is to keep track of unique Ids and count only unique Occurences to that id, like a count, but after i have the id i.e ID=1 UniqueOccurences = 3, but each occurnce has multiple tuples waiting. Just like a unique object holding multiple values

Comment: I updated the OP with an example of the desired result I want

Comment: "count of unique Occurences arriving at id 1,2 and 3." so that would be counting with the key being the id? But that count would result in a map of id to count value --- what does that have to do with a list? Your requirements are unclear and by throwing some half-baked design in there it gets impossible to understand. Suggest to be very clear with requirements.

Comment: Found out, using distinct count in the crate table statement